# How to change meta tag image dynamically in reactjs for sharing of link on Facebook, WhatsApp or any platform

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic, components, meta-tags

I need to display the image for a link when sharing on Facebook, WhatsApp or any platform.
It worked when added in index.html but I need to add the image in component because the image is dynamic. I tried with react-meta-tag but did not work, Please help me.

```
return (
    <div className="wx-1120px border-box pxl-10px">
      <MetaTags>
        <title>title app.js</title>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="The Rock Photo Studio" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock Photo Studio in Florida" />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content="The best photo studio for your events"
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content="https://thewedpostamit.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1584017948002WK2_4905.jpg"
        />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
        <meta
          property="og:url"
          content="https://thewedpost.com/stories/varsha-and-ram-from-college-sweethearts-to-happily-ever-after"
        />
      </MetaTags>
      <h3 className="wx-100precent fsx-48px din-bo alText-center mxb-15px">
        Test Title{" "}
      </h3>
      <img
        src="https://thewedpostamit.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1584017948002WK2_4905.jpg"
        alt="test"
        height="300"
        width="300"
      />
      <p className="alText-center din-re fsx-14px color-HEX666666 mxb-30px">
        Published by - Test User | 8 minute read
      </p>

      <style jsx>{`
        .word-wrap {
          word-wrap: break-word;
          text-align: justify;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?

Comment: I was using next.js and next.ja provide next/head module for head section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need server side rendering to make crawlers(fb, tw, etc...) see your open graph tags. Dynamically adding on client side does not work. Crawlers can see only static html.